# go.mod use modules without tags

Tags: go, go-gin, go-modules, go-get

I use [gin-gonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) for my rest API.

I have a problem with it.

The latest tag is `v1.6.3` but in `master` branch there is a method that I want to use.

What do I put in the `go.mod` to use the `master` branch instead the latest tag?

Note:

- the method I want to use is `CustomRecovery()` method that available in the `master` branch but isn't present in `v1.6.3`

Update:

Here is my go.mod

```golang
go 1.15

require (
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin 16cd8cdd4ef9
)
```

but when I run go mod download it changes automatically to this

```golang
go 1.15

require (
    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.6.3-0.20201025090830-16cd8cdd4ef9
    github.com/joho/godotenv v1.3.0
    gorm.io/driver/mysql v1.0.3
    gorm.io/gorm v1.20.5
)
```

And it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible by following the documentation "[How to Upgrade and Downgrade Dependencies](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies)

A simple `go get  example.com/package` is enough to modify the go.mod and use the latest version of a specific dependency.
To upgrade a dependency and *all its dependencies* to the latest version:

```
go get -u example.com/package
```

That is:

> `go get foo` updates to the latest version of `foo`.
> `go get foo` is equivalent to `go get foo@latest` — in other words, `@latest` is the default if no `@` version is specified.

And:

> A common mistake is thinking `go get -u foo` solely gets the latest version of `foo`.
> In actuality, the `-u` in `go get -u foo` or `go get -u foo@latest` means to also get the latest versions for all of the direct and indirect dependencies of `foo`.
>
> A common starting point when upgrading foo is instead to do `go get foo` or `go get foo@latest` *without* a `-u` (and after things are working, consider `go get -u=patch foo`, `go get -u=patch`, `go get -u foo`, or `go get -u`).

Comment: How my go.mod should look like?

Comment: @YoviPrasetyo After a go get, you should see a line ending with the resolve tag/sha, as seen in https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#version-validation. Make sure to use the latest Go version you can (1.13+, preferably 1.15.x)

Comment: @YoviPrasetyo Your go.mod looks good: as expected, the dependency is identified with its exact tag/SHA.